# Sailsjs: can't create dummy object on bootstrap with Date attribute

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, sails.js

I'm able to create to create a dummy user object at bootstrap before adding a "Date" attribute. In bootstrap.js I have:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
    var dummyData = [
        {
            "firstName":"Jane",
            "lastName":"Doe",
            "dateofbirth": 1279703658 //timestamp
        }
    ]

    User.count().exec(function(err, count){
        if(err){
            return cb(err);
        }

        if(count == 0){
            User.create(dummyData).exec(function(){
                cb();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

User.js is simple and looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    firstName : {
        type : 'string',
        required : true
    },
    lastName : {
        type : 'string',
        required : true
    },

    dateofbirth : {
        type : 'date'
    }
  }
};
```

when I try creating the same object in browser (sails nice CRUD functionality) I get an error about the date:

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "User",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "dateofbirth": [
      {
        "rule": "date",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a date (instead of \"123454345\",     which is a string)"
      }
   ]
 }
}
```

So question is how can I create such object with date attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` (or the equivalent `dateTime`) accepts e.g. an ISO date string. So, your example could look like:

```
var dummyData = [
        {
            "firstName":"Jane",
            "lastName":"Doe",
             // "1970-01-15T19:28:23.658Z"
            "dateofbirth": new Date(1279703658).toISOString() 
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't realize that!

Comment: @sleeveroller No problem :) You can check the [date ranges](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) here for other alternatives.

Comment: I think you can actually just do `new Date(1279703658)`, sails will accept also a date object